# Where in London should you bring a fan of the band Madness?

Tags: london, sightseeing

I'm going to London with a huge fan of the band Madness. Is there anywhere special I could go with him as a nice surprise?

I know that the members of the band grew up there. I guess their videos were made in London too. I was wondering if there are some known places in London that would be nice to see for a fan. Like the zebra crossing is for a fan of the Beatles, for example.

Comment: Did you try a ticket agent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_rYTV3j3X4) suggests that many locations in Camden have links to Madness music videos. It also gives suggested tube stations and walking routes to visit these places.

Comment: A summary of at least a couple of those places would be nice. This isn't much better than just a link as it stands.

Answer (score 3):

If you can schedule it so you're in London over the Easter long weekend - too late now for this year, but you could come next year (24 to 27 March 2016) - then you could visit the [London International Ska Festival](http://www.londoninternationalskafestival.co.uk/), which includes events such as:

> - Madness Special – a tribute to Camden Town’s finest (7pm-midnight) at the Camden Foundry, Camden. Free entry.
> - Prince Charles cinema in Leicester Sq (screening Madness’ 1981 Take It or Leave It film)
> - Phoenix City All-stars present a truly unique celebration of one of Britain’s most iconic labels. Taking some of 2 Tone’s greatest songs by The Specials, Madness, The Beat, Elvis Costello and The Selecter and replanting in 1960′s Jamaica.
> - THE LEE THOMPSON SKA ORCHESTRA: The brainchild of Madness saxophonist Mr. Lee ‘Kix’ Thompson, The Ska Orchestra boasts an all-star/hand-picked line up that features fellow Madness original Mark Bedford

Those were part of the 2015 festival, but I can't think that the 2016 festival won't have some similar Madness-themed events as part of it. That would be .... (drum-roll please) ... madness!